# How to change tableview images when user clicks on a cell

Tags: ios, uitableview

i have a table view of six cell for each cell i set a different color .my question is when user clicks on a particular cell i want to change color of all cells to orange color except user clicked cell .

Comment: So what is wrong? Did you try to use [UITableViewDelegate](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UITableViewDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html) methods?

Comment: - (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{   
            
            if (indexPath.row==i) {
                
                //reamin same color
                
            }
            else if (indexPath.row!=i){
               
               //set color to orange
            }    
  }  i have used above method but there is no use is there any other delegate method,if there is please mention it

Comment: Can you please mention delegate method and implement ion of it

Comment: When you click that particular cell, `indexPath.row == i` will always be true, because `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` is only called with the index path of the selected cell. You should loop through in this method for all of your cells and change their colors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this...

declare a global NSInteger variable. lets say `selectedIndex`

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath { 
selectedIndex = indexPath.row;
[tableview reload];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
 if (indexPath.row == selectedIndex) { <set BG as some color> } else { <set BG as orange> } 
}
```

Comment: if the answer helped you, can you upvote and click the tick icon to the left of this answer.